# Mousclick vs keypress

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

While making sounds with the keyboard my teacher used:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
---------------function-body-----------
});
```

And with a mouseclick, he used

```
document.addEventListener("click, function(){
var drum = this.innerHTML;
```

I am not understanding why "event" cannot be used with mouseclick?

Comment: Because it can and does work (just with slightly different properties)

Comment: Your teacher didn't use event, but you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event` property, it usually is just not necessary with a mouse click.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var drum = this.innerHTML;
});
```

The above code is perfectly valid Javascript.
Just a note, make sure you terminate your strings with `"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event` interface with any event. You don't always need it however but it's always passed regardless.

These are the [MDN Docs on what the event interface is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Here is a simple example of one way the event interface is useful, and a very simple (a bit unrealistic) use case of when you might not need it.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div');

container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   // Event contains data about the event, such as the element that triggered it.
   event.target.textContent = 'you clicked me!';
});

const input = document.querySelector('input');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
   // You don't need the event for the below side effect.
   output.textContent = `You've entering some text.`;
});
```

```html
<div>
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
</div>

<input />
<div class='output'></div>
```